# How do I mount a linux filesystem harddisk to a Windows server?

Tags: amazon-ec2, hard-drive

When I try to mount a linux filesystem harddisk to a Windows server. It will show that the harddisk is not initialized and unallocated in computer management, but it simply does not show up as A drive letter (such as D:) https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZXCs.png

I think it is a centOS 6.2 harddisk (aki-88aa75e1) https://i.stack.imgur.com/7x24h.png

Comment: Nice of you to downvote several correct answers below...

Answer (score 2):

**My personal favorites are**

### [Ext2Fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/)

and

### [Ext2Read (formerly Ext2Explore)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/)

The former being the driver of choice.  Very lightweight, full-featured and works with all ext's (*ext2, ext3, ext4*).

The latter is mainly a secondary option for you to have more choices.

Enjoy :)

Comment: Ext2Fsd only shows that the type is RAW. it does not show other info, like harddisk size.. Ext2Read shows nothing, not even when I click rescan system (on Windows Server 2008)

Comment: It might not extend the support it has for ext2/3 to the newer ext4. But it has full R/W support for ext2,3,4.  And as for seeing it in My Computer you'll have to mount it through the GUI and/or Comp Mgmt (sorry it's been a while).  Are you looking to do something specific while it's in that server or just move data to an NTFS partition somewhere and call it a day?

Comment: Yes, just move the data to an NTFS partition. I think the RAW partition is on centos 6.2

Comment: Oh it only says RAW but once you mount it you just assign the drive letter and you're in EXT4.  Let me know if you get stuck at all

Comment: How do I suppose to do that in this window: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7x24h.png

Comment: That's not right.  Did you DL version 0.51 and during setup select all the checkboxes?

Answer (score 1):

Windows as shipped, knows nothing about how to mount "linux filesystems". You'll need to install a third-party filesystem driver to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Of course not. Windows doesn't support Linux file systems and it simply doesn't know what to with them. You will need to check if there is a 3rd party Windows driver for the filesystem on the disk (hint: There are different types of file systems used on Linux, like ext3/4, XFS, JFS, ReiserFS). And no, I don't have a recommendation for a driver.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install an ext4 driver windows. Ext4 is name of the de facto standard filesystem in linux. There are many different software for this, for example here is one:

http://www.paragon-software.com/home/extfs-windows/